# kubernetes create service account token without expiration

Tags: kubernetes

I created a token for my service account using the command 'kubectl create token admin-user'. But after a while it becomes unusable and I have to create it again. How can I generate a token for my service account without expire time?

Comment: Service account tokens have an expiration of one hour. In earlier Kubernetes versions, the tokens didn't have an expiration. so which version you are using? and cloud provider?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the token for one year using the below command. You can define duration as appropriate, say **--duration=87600h for 10 years** and so on

```
kubectl create token admin-user --duration=8760h
```

Comment: please upvote and chose it as the answer

Comment: sorry, my reputation is not enough

Comment: they short the time to 172800 seconds (48 hours)

`Warning: requested expiration of 31536000 seconds shortened to 172800 seconds`

Answer (score 5):

As of v1.24, when using `kubectl create token --duration` it will not allow the creation of long lived tokens

This can be now be accomplished via the manual approach as explained in the official documentation.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#manually-create-a-long-lived-api-token-for-a-serviceaccount

Answer (score 0):

The option --duration 0s ensures that the token will never expire

```
--duration 0s
```